# Distributional derivatives

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I need to compute derivatives as distributions of following functions:

$f(x) =$

1. $|x|$
2. $|x^2 - 1|$
3. $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$
4. $4$

Where $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

**ad 1)**
$|x|$ is continuous, so it belongs to $L^1_{loc}(\Omega) \Rightarrow$ its derivative exists.

I know, that

$$
\left< F', \phi \right> = - \left< F, \phi' \right> = -\int_\Omega f(x) \varphi'(x) dx
$$

So now, I'm trying to compute the derivative of $|x|$:

\begin{align}
- \left< F, \varphi' \right> &= - \int_\Omega |x| \varphi'(x) dx \\
&=
- \int^0_{- \infty} -x \cdot \varphi'(x) dx - \int^{\infty}_0 x \cdot \varphi'(x) dx \\
&=
\left[ x \cdot \varphi(x) \right]^0_{- \infty} - \int^0_{- \infty} 1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx - \left[ x \cdot \varphi(x) \right]^{+ \infty}_0 + \int^{+ \infty}_0 1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx
\end{align}

And here I'm hopelessly lost. The result is supposed to be

$$
\int^{+ \infty}_{- \infty} g(x)\varphi(x) dx,
$$

where

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & x>0\\
-1, & x< 0
\end{cases},
$$

but I have literally no idea, how should I proceed. E.g.

$$
\left[ x \cdot \varphi(x) \right]^0_{- \infty} = 0 - \left( -\infty \cdot \varphi(-\infty) \right)
$$

is supposed to be $0$, but still, I have no idea why...

So, could you, please, describe me, how to compute this derivative of a distribution and explain it a little?

---

#### Edit:

Ok, Thanks to the Zachary Selk's answer I understand why the result of square brackets is 0. Then we have just the sum of two remaining integrals:

\begin{align}
- \int^0_{- \infty} 1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx + \int^{\infty}_{0} 1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx &= \int^0_{- \infty} -1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx + \int^{\infty}_{0} 1 \cdot \varphi(x) dx\\
&= \int^{\infty}_{- \infty} g(x) sgn(x) dx\\
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
1, & x > 0\\
-1, & x < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Ok, I'm able to understand this.

---

**ad 2)**

$$
|x^2 - 1| = \begin{cases}
x^2 - 1, & x < -1\\
1 - x^2, & x \in \left< -1;1 \right>\\
x^2 -1, & x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

I can see, that when $x < -1$ or $x > 1$ the integral does not converge. So, the only one remaining to compute is

\begin{align}
\int^{1}_{-1} (1-x^2) \varphi'(x) dx &= 
2 \int^1_0 (1-x^2)\varphi'(x) dx\\
&= 2 \left( [(1-x^2)\varphi(x)]^1_0
- \int_0^1 -2x \cdot \varphi(x) dx
 \right)\\
&= -2 \varphi(0) +4 \int^1_0 x \varphi(x) dx
\end{align}

And here I'm lost again, I think that only per partes will not help me with this integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that $\varphi \in S(\Bbb{R})$ or $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$. Either way $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} x\varphi(x)=0$

Comment: Ok... Probably $\varphi(\infty)=0$. But then we have the product $0 \cdot \infty$ and that's the undefined operation, isn't it?

Comment: @Eenoku $\varphi(\infty)$ doesn't make any sense. Remember you are taking a limit.

Comment: So, $\varphi(x)$ is 0 outside it's bounded support. So, when I'm going to $\infty$ with limit, its value will be 0, ok?

Comment: @Eenoku That is correct.

Comment: But, I'm not sure, why the limit of its product with $x$ is not changing the limit's value...

Comment: @Eenoku Because out of some set, $x \varphi(x)=0$

Comment: Could you, please, explain it a little more? I'm afraid, I don't understand now.

Comment: @Eenoku It's just limits.  $\lim_{x\to \infty} x\varphi(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} 0=0$

Comment: I mean, specifically, why is $x \varphi(x) = 0$?

Comment: @Eenoku Because $\varphi(x)=0$ outside of some interval. Remember $\text{anything} \cdot 0=0$. In particular $x\cdot 0=0$ outside of some interval.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've updated my question with info about my attempt with second example.